# Can i use document.querySelectorAll() instead of document.getElementsByClassName() to work well in IE8?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="abcd"></div>
<script>
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('abcd');
var x = document.querySelectorAll("abcd");
alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());
alert(x[0].hasChildNodes());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code first alert give false but not in alert two. how do i get same result with document.querySelectorAll ?
basically i want it to work in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll()` uses the same selectors as CSS to address elements. So instead of using `"abcd"` as parameter, you should go for `".abcd"` (note the added `.`) there.

```
<script>
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('abcd');
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".abcd");
alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());
alert(x[0].hasChildNodes());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use proper [css selectors (v2.1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html): `var x = document.querySelectorAll(".abcd");`

See also [this page](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) for browser support of css selectors